# Why all the synthesized copy control operations are noexcept by dedault?

Tags: c++, noexcept

For curiosity sake I'd like to know the default exception specification for default (synthesized) Copy Control Operations.

Here is what I've tried:

```
struct Foo{
   Foo() = default;
   Foo(Foo const&) = default;
   Foo(Foo&&) = default;
   Foo& operator=(Foo const&) = default;
   Foo& operator=(Foo&&) = default;
   ~Foo() = default;
};


int main(){

    Foo f1, f2;
    std::cout << noexcept( Foo{} ) << '\n';
    std::cout << noexcept( Foo(f2) ) << '\n';
    std::cout << noexcept( Foo(std::move(f1)) ) << '\n';
    std::cout << noexcept( f1.operator=(f2) ) << '\n';
    std::cout << noexcept( f1.operator=(std::move(f2)) ) << '\n';
    std::cout << noexcept( f1.~Foo() ) << '\n';
  
    std::cout << "\ndone!\n";    
}
```

The output:

```
1
1
1
1
1
1
```

- Why all the synthesized special members are `noexcept`?

Comment: Why not? What could throw when they are executed? Try adding a member variable like `std::string`.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica OK! one last thing: why if I define all copy-ctrl operations without `noexcept` then they are all throwing but onyl the 4destructor? `st52ruct F{~Foo(){} Foo(Foo&&){}};` the dtor is still `noexcept` but move-ctor is throwing now?

Comment: Any destructor since C++11 is implicitly noexcept unless **explicitly** made otherwise with `noexcept(false)`. Throwing from destructors is best avoided. The standard library in particular gives no guarantees (undefined behavior) if you instantiate a container with a type whose destructor throws.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica: Thank you! get it now.

Answer (score 1):

The biggest reason: Performance

Take `std::vector` for example.  When it grows, it has to copy the buffer to maintain the exception guarantee that the original vector is preserved if an exception happens.  If the element type is noexcpt move constructible, then the vector can move the elements instead and not have to worry about maintaining the exception guarantee that the original vector isn't lost if an exception happens.

There are other containers/functions that leverage this same thing, and doing so is a performance win.

Having to require you to do this yourself would be a waste as the compiler is perfectly capable to deducing if the default can be noexcept or not.